# Identify which company manages a domain

Tags: dns, domain-name

How would I go about identifying what company manages a domain name? I have a new client who's wanting me to take over the development of her website due to the fact that her previous website consultant is no longer responding to her inquiries. She has no idea who is managing the domain she owns, so I'm trying to see if it's possible to identify the company such that she doesn't have to register a new domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with a whois lookup: http://www.whois.net/ and make phone calls from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ["Who Is"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) tool for getting information about a registered domain name.

http://whois.domaintools.com is such an site. [Example record for Google](http://whois.domaintools.com/google.com).

Answer (score 1):

A whois lookup should give you the current contact list for a domain (registrant, administrator, tech contact). See http://www.whois.net/. If the domain was registered with a "private" registration, though, all you may get is the registrar's information.

Answer (score 0):

Go to : http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx and type whois:yourdomain name in the seach box

Answer (score 0):

This is a common need and can be done with a simple search. You can look it up here: https://whoownsthedomain.com/